# How to export Json to excel in angular2 or angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a Angular2 component in which I am using Html table.I have a button when I click the button then I want all the data of table should export into excel file.

How can I do that Please help me

Comment: You can't create files directly from a Javascript app. You need a backend service Server side or use an underlying native service if the app is hosted on a mobile platform.

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/javiertelioz/angular2-csv

Comment: Thank you hrdkisback.But I want to export as an excel file not as CSV.I am looking for excel export and your link above is for csv export.Please help me if possible.

Comment: An excel file isn't as simple as a csv. They aren't saved in a human readable format and like with docx files I'd like to think of them more as a package than a single file.

Open an excel file with 7zip or another archive program and you'll see what I mean.